# KVM: VPN'd Host, Guest Needs VPN & Host Access for NFS

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, linux-kvm

I'm running an Ubuntu guest in KVM, which is in turn running on an Ubuntu host.  The host network goes through a VPN (OpenVPN), providing tun0.  I need the guest network to also go through the VPN, except that I need to be able to reach the host via the network for a filesystem mounted via NFS.

Host address is 192.168.10.10
Router address is 192.168.10.1
tun0 is 10.8.8.16

I don't care if my guest is NAT'd or bridged, or even if I have to use a second network interface.  Anyone have an approach that might work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to use the default VM setup, with the network NAT'd.  Then the VM will have addresses in the 192.168.122.0/24 range, while the host machine will be made available at 192.168.122.1.  As long as the host is connected to the internet through a VPN, then VM will likewise connect through the VPN.  While the host will be reachable at it's local address, in this case 192.168.10.10, that connection will have to go through the router.  In my case the connection to the router is slow but my local switch is fast, so using KVM's default 192.168.122.1 host address is substantially faster for NFS transfers.